# Elasticsearch - use EdgeNGram analyzer for case insensitive search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to make case insensitive search on fields with EdgeNGram analyzer. I am using ES in php via [elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica).

I have table of users

```
{
   "user": {
      "analyzer": "analyzer_edgeNGram",
      "properties": {
         "admin": {
            "type": "boolean"
         },
         "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "analyzer_edgeNGram"
         },
         "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "analyzer_edgeNGram"
         },
         "username": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "analyzer_edgeNGram"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My analyzers look like this (you can see there is lowercase filter in egdeNGram analyzer)

```
         "index.analysis.filter.asciifolding.type": "asciifolding",
         "index.number_of_replicas": "1",
         "index.analysis.filter.standard.type": "standard",
         "index.analysis.tokenizer.edgeNGram.token_chars.1": "digit",
         "index.analysis.tokenizer.edgeNGram.max_gram": "10",
         "index.analysis.analyzer.analyzer_edgeNGram.type": "custom",
         "index.analysis.tokenizer.edgeNGram.token_chars.0": "letter",
         "index.analysis.filter.lowercase.type": "lowercase",
         "index.analysis.tokenizer.edgeNGram.side": "front",
         "index.analysis.tokenizer.edgeNGram.type": "edgeNGram",
         "index.analysis.tokenizer.edgeNGram.min_gram": "1",
         "index.analysis.tokenizer.standard.type": "standard",
         "index.analysis.analyzer.analyzer_edgeNGram.filters": "standard,lowercase,asciifolding",
         "index.analysis.analyzer.analyzer_edgeNGram.tokenizer": "edgeNGram",
         "index.number_of_shards": "1",
         "index.version.created": "900299"
```

There is for example user with firstName Miroslav. If I do query like this

```
{"query": {"match": {"firstName": "miro"}}}
```

I have 0 hits. But if I changed in query miro to Miro it will find.
I've checked how are the tokens generated and they are case sensitive: M, Mi, Mir, ...

Any advice how to achieve case insensitive searching?
Thank you

Comment: It looks like your filters are not being applied to the generated tokens. Can you copy and paste your index mappings? Are you manually creating lowercase and standard filters?

Comment: Definetly the filters aren't applied. When I create the analyzer via PHP framework that is using ruflin's elastica the settings are  

`"index.analysis.analyzer.analyzer_edgeNGram.filters": "standard,lowercase,asciifolding"`    . But when I create it via curl command the settings are `"index.analysis.analyzer.analyzer_edgeNGram.filter.0": "lowercase","index.analysis.analyzer.analyzer_edgeNGram.filter.1": "asciifolding","index.analysis.analyzer.analyzer_edgeNGram.filter.2": "standard"`. So I guess it will be in the framework I'm using.

Comment: One the tokens are generated with case sensitivity there's not much you can do, is it possible to re-index your data and add a lowercase filter to your analyzer?

Answer (score 0):

The default `search_analyzer` set is `standard` and has the following settings:

```
"analyzer": {
  "rebuilt_standard": {
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase"       
    ]
  }
}
```

So by default your queries must be case insensitive, but you can allways try to set the value of search_analyzer to something else. In the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html):

> Sometimes, though, it can make sense to use a different analyzer at search time, such as when using the edge_ngram tokenizer for autocomplete.
>
> By default, queries will use the analyzer defined in the field mapping, but this can be overridden with the search_analyzer setting: